# How to re-develop double tonguing?

Tags: technique, trumpet, brass, breathing, tonguing

Two years ago, I had no issue double- and triple-tonguing. After a while, however, I seem to have issues playing quickly enough. I suspect that I have gone back to single-tonguing. How can I go back to being able to double-tongue on Trumpet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, Samuel, I've gotten away from my double-tonguing but found some excellent suggestions on this website:

http://www.trumpetmaster.com/vb/f131/learning-how-double-tongue-64418.html

It seems that building speed slowly, using the mouthpiece only, and using tu-ku (heavying up on the ku's until clear) are the highlights of the advice offered on this site.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

Like the other answer, it's a matter of starting off slowly and building up speed when you practice. The technique I find most helpful for double-tonguing is to double-tongue scales in a variety of ways:

1. four beats (tu-ku tu-ku) per note
2. two beats (tu-ku) per note
3. one beat (tu or ku!) per note

I've also found the exercises in [Arban's Cornet Method](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Arban-Cornet-Method-Book-Fitz-Gerald/dp/B0063LMVWK) really useful (it's an enormous book full of studies on every technique).

Comment: I have Arban's, but I still have trouble double-tounging the exercises.